# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, classnotfoundexception

I was using spring 3.0.5 and hibernate 3.6.35 for my application and now I have migrated to spring 4.3.2 version with hibernate 5.2.1.

Here is the hibernate.xml

```
  <bean id="sessionFactory"
          parent="annotatedClassList"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="eventListeners">
            <map>
                <entry key="post-insert" value-ref="auditEventListener"/>
                <entry key="post-update" value-ref="auditEventListener"/>
                <entry key="post-delete" value-ref="auditEventListener"/>
                <entry key="pre-collection-update" value-ref="auditEventListener"/>
                <entry key="pre-collection-remove" value-ref="auditEventListener"/>
                <entry key="post-collection-recreate" value-ref="auditEventListener"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="auditEventListener" class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
```

I am getting the following error:-

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener] for bean with name 'auditEventListener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:980)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1402)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    ... 23 more
```

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: You haven't shown us the definition of the missing bean. Please provide a [mcve]. Why shouldn't the exception be thrown?

Comment: Where you define the bean `auditEventListener`

Comment: Most probably you should check your configuration whether you have specified a bean with name auditEventListener, there could be a spelling mistake or even if you have specified a bean with name auditEventListener. If you have defined a bean named auditEventListner then check where have you defined it and if spring is able to load that xml.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  sorry. I was disabled the bean before. Now I have enabled the bean and updated my question. Kindly take a look.

Comment: With newer versions of hibernate (and hibernate envers) you don't need to register the listener anymore. This is now done automatically. YOu can remove that part of your configuration and Envers will still work.

Comment: http://www.warski.org/blog/2011/04/envers-and-hibernate-4-0-0-alpha2-automatic-listener-registration/